# MongoDB - Update field or Add field if not present on BsonDocument C#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-.net-driver

I am trying to store any JSON provided to an API into a BsonDocument, which is a field on another document using the C# driver

However when i try to use the UpdateOne method, it just replaces the document with whatever i submit. Here is my top level mongo document

```
public class SomeMongoDocument 
{
    public ObjectId _id { get; set; }

    public string FileName { get; set; }

    public BsonDocument Metadata { get; set; }
}
```

I want to set the Metadata property initially, and then update it later on, the update may not contain all of the initial Metadata sent. So when i try to update the document with this:

```
public void UpdateMetadata(string filename, string metadata)
{
        var filter = Builders<SomeMongoDocument>.Filter.Eq(e => e.FileName, filename;

        BsonDocument document = BsonSerializer.Deserialize<BsonDocument>(metadata);

        var update = Builders<SomeMongoDocument>.Update.Set(e => e.Metadata, document);

        this.MongoCollection.UpdateOne(filter, update);

}
```

It just overwrites the BsonDocument and deletes properties that are not present in the string when i convert it into a bson document.

So how can i do the following:

Update an existing property, or when adding new properties, preserve what was already there. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{ $set: { "metadata": { ... } } }` replaces the whole `metadata` embedded document. If you want to replace the values inside embedded document, you should specify them in `$set` operator like:

{ $set: { "metadata.innerField1": "SomeValue1", "metadata.innerField2": "SomeValue2" }

or with MongoDB .Net Driver:

```
Builders<SomeMongoDocument>.Update
    .Set(e => e.Metadata.InnerField1, document.InnerField1)
    .Set(e => e.Metadata.InnerField2, document.InnerField2)
    // ...
```

Since you don't have predefined properties in your document, you can't hardcode them in the code in this way. In this case you can just enumerate `BsonDocument` elements and add them to update definition:

```
UpdateDefinition<SomeMongoDocument> update = null;
foreach (BsonElement element in document)
{
    update = update?.Set(e => e.Metadata[element.Name], element.Value) ??
                Builders<SomeMongoDocument>.Update.Set(e => e.Metadata[element.Name], element.Value);
}

if (update != null)
{
    this.MongoCollection.UpdateOne(filter, update);
}
```